# What distribution am I looking for? Bayesian statistics

Tags: statistics, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

Here's a question from an old exam paper, I am struggling to understand how to construct an answer:
"A six-sided die has an unknown number of faces marked with a
six. Let $k$ be this unknown number, which we would like to estimate.When the die is thrown each face has an equal chance of showing. The observed data is that
the die was thrown twice, and it showed a six exactly once. Write down the likelihood for the observed data. What is the maximum likelihood
estimate for $k$?"

I really just don't get how to start this. I think I need to decide what distribution the observed data comes from, but when I try a binomial distribution, I end up with only being able to estimate the probability of getting a six given the data, not the number of sixes on the die.

EDIT: With thanks to user ***Mees de Vries***, I believe I may have found a way to model the problem correctly. Say the die has $k$ faces with a six on them, $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Then, say we have rolled the die $n$ times and observed $m$ successes, where success is rolling a six. Then we could treat this as $$m \sim \text{Bin}(n,k/6) $$
Then of course, the MLE is $$\frac{\hat{k}}{6}=\frac{m}{n} \implies \hat{k}=\frac{6m}{n}$$ Our observed data is that $m=1,n=2$ so here $\hat{k}=6(1)/2=3$
Which matches my intuition in the comments. Now, is my logic correct?

Comment: You are _extremely close_ to the right answer. You have found a probability $p$ that "best models" your outcome. How many sides of.a six-sided die should be successes so that this corresponds to $p$? (Somewhat harder question: what if the die had been thrown $18$ times, and you had seen a six $10$ of those $18$ times?)

Comment: @MeesdeVries From a common-sense POV, it feels most likely that if I rolled 1 6 and 1 of something else, then I had $1/2$ a chance of seeing a 6, given what I have observed. So I'd say there should be 3 6s on the die. But, if that is correct, how could I translate my common sense answer into mathematics?

Comment: Yes, your logic is correct. To make sure you actually understand, though, I recommend reflecting on my "10 sixes out of 18" example. :-)

Comment: @MeesdeVries if you haven't seen my edit, I think that should cover the 10 sixes out of 18. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In that case, you get $\hat k = 60/18 = 10/3$. That's not a number of sides, though, because it's not an integer!

Comment: @MeesdeVries I see. Is my solution wrong then or is that just a quirk of the problem?

Comment: Your solution isn't wrong -- certainly your answer is correct. But if it's not clear what to do in the case of "10 out of 18 sixes" there may still be a gap in your understanding. Note that you say "we could treat this as $m \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n, k/6)$, but in fact it should be "$m \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n, k/6)$ _where $k$ is an integer_".

Comment: @MeesdeVries Oh I see what you mean now, thank you for the help.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the MLE is not always "the integer nearest to $6m/n$", because this could have ties (e.g. $m/n=7/12$). Interestingly, since the likelihood function is proportional to $k^m(6-k)^{n-m}$ --which always has the same parity as $k$--it's not possible for the likelihood function to have ties (because a tie would have to be with consecutive integers).

Answer (score 0):

Two long for a comment. I didn't unerstand what die is.

My approach to do your question without "Binom":

We have two expectations. The first one is fake expectation. In your problem, fake expectation is $E_f=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{k}{6})6=\sum_{i=1}^nk=kn$. On the other hand we have the reality, real expactation. Here, it is $E_r=6m$ because we are $m$ times succesful. From the conversation of expactations, $E_f=E_r\implies kn=6m\implies k=\frac{6m}{n}$.

Comment: Here *die* is the singular of *dice*, typically a cube with six equally likely faces.  Usually the faces are marked $1,2,3,4,5,6$ but in this question there may be more than one face with a $6$.  The question asks for the number of faces with $6$s which maximise likelihood given the observation, rather than an expectation; in particular it should be an integer